# Why does my Servlet Filter run twice?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, servlet-filters, embedded-jetty

I have a simple Servlet filter:

```
package net.twentyonesolutions;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println(TestFilter.class.getSimpleName()       // line 12
                + " > "
                + ((HttpServletRequest)servletRequest).getRequestURL()
                + ": IP "+ servletRequest.getRemoteAddr()
                + "; at "
                + new Date().toString());

        // Pass request back down the filter chain
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);    // line 20
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    public void destroy() {}
}
```

I added it to web.xml like so:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>TestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.twentyonesolutions.TestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>TestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I am running it in debug mode in IntelliJ IDEA with an embedded Jetty.  I expect the output from line 12 to be written once, but instead it is written twice, and both times are before the Servlet is called.

Why is it called twice?  Is it supposed to be called twice?  If so, how can I tell the first time from the second time, because I want my code to only run once.

I found a couple of old questions about this issue, but none had a real solution or explanation.

You can see the diff of the stack trace between the 1st call and the 2nd call in the screenshot below:

[image]

### UPDATE

When I deploy the filter to regular (not-embedded) Jetty (same version as the embedded one, `9.2.18.v20160721`) or Tomcat -- `doFilter()` is only executed once per request, as expected, so the issue is either with the debugging in IntelliJ IDEA or with the embedded Jetty.

### Update embed code:

```
    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setContextPath("/");
    webapp.setResourceBase(webRoot);
    webapp.setDefaultsDescriptor(webRoot + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");     

    Server server = new Server();

    ServerConnector http = new ServerConnector(server);
    http.setPort(port);             
    if (!host.equals(""))
        http.setHost(host);

    server.setConnectors(new ServerConnector[] { http });
    server.setHandler(webapp);      
    server.start();
    server.join();
```

### Update filterChain.toString()

I added a print of filterChain.toString() just before the call `filterChain.doFilter()` and it shows the difference clearly.

The first object in the `filterChain` (before the first call to `doFilter()`), is my filter.  See the two printed lines:

```
TestFilter > fdvnqp1k0ut37fenee569vshqf http://localhost:8080/index.cfm: IP 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; at Tue Sep 06 09:59:09 PDT 2016
    ... filterChain: TestFilter->CFMLServlet@cdad6a3==lucee.debug.loader.servlet.CFMLServlet,1,true
TestFilter > fdvnqp1k0ut37fenee569vshqf http://localhost:8080/index.cfm: IP 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; at Tue Sep 06 09:59:09 PDT 2016
    ... filterChain: CFMLServlet@cdad6a3==lucee.debug.loader.servlet.CFMLServlet,1,true
```

I'm not sure about the spec, but I expect my `TestFilter` to be removed from the chain before `TestFilter.doFilter()` is called the first time, no?

Comment: A redirect? So you see two requests.

Comment: Where would the redirect come from?  And if that's the case, how come the Servlet is only called once?

Comment: To further confirm, I tried different `<dispatcher>` attributes.  Only `REQUEST` causes the filter to run, which is what I expected as I'm hitting the server with simple http GET requests.  All other types, i.e. FORWARD, INCLUDE, and ERROR do not trigger the filter at all.

Comment: If you vote this question down, please explain why.  At the very least it is written very clearly IMO.

Comment: @Thor: stack trace in right hand side confirms that it's happening in one and same HTTP request. In other words, there are indeed two separate instances of the very same filter class mapped in the webapp.

Comment: Can you show your embedded code ?

Comment: I agree with @sbordet, We would need to see your embedded-jetty code  to answer this.

Comment: The embed code is very straightforward, and takes a web descriptor `/WEB-INF/web.xml`.  See updated section in the question above.

Comment: @BalusC After reading your comment I added a `String filterId` to the TestFilter class, and initialized it with `SecureRandom`, i.e. `new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32)` inside TestFilter's `init()`.  I am outputting it inside `init()` as well as in line 12 of `doFilter()`.  `init()` is only called once, as expected.  `doFilter()` shows the same `filterId` for both invocations.

Comment: @sbordet @joakim-erdfelt - Please see my update with showing `filterChain.toString()` -- is this a bug in embedded Jetty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are setting WEB-INF/web.xml as the defaults descriptor.   So the web.xml is being run twice - once to set the defaults and once as the discovered WEB-INF/web.xml - so you are getting two instances of the filter.

Don't set the defaults descriptor (or set it to null if you want know defaults - but then you will not have a default servlet).

Comment: So you mean call `webapp.setDescriptor()` instead of `webapp.setDefaultDecriptor()`?

Comment: Thank you, Greg!  And thanks for creating the Jetty project :)